# Простой и удобный дизайнер для оконных приложений в CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, дизайнер

Ситуация следующая. Раньше мы в нашем учебном центре учили программировать на C++ в среде C++ Builder, где с дизайнерами всё было в порядке. Теперь мы перешли на CodeBlocks, и я не знаю, существуют ли там аналогичный дизайнер форм, **который можно показать и освоить за одно занятие**. Там вроде бы есть возможность подключить wxWidgets и QT. Есть ли смысл с этими инструментами разбираться, или они всё равно будут слишком сложны для новичков? Если для CodeBlocks нет WISIWYG-дизайнера форм, придётся вообще отказываться от этой темы.

Comment: А Qt Designer вам чем не угодил?

Comment: Если он подходит для моей задачи, буду с ним разбираться. Мне нужен совет от знающих людей.

Comment: А взять и попробовать - не? "будут слишком сложны для новичков" - никто, кроме новичков это вам не скажет.

Comment: http://rusdir.blogspot.ru/2010/10/qt-codeblocks.html ну, например, вот такое явно не вдохновляет. Это даже не сложная настройка, а какой-то workaround к отчёту о багах. Где вообще было бы подробно расписано такое? Может, книга хотя бы есть?

Comment: Это 2010 год... Не хотите пробовать - не пробуйте.

Comment: wxWidgets = есть такая вещь, как Anthemion DialogBlocks. Как по мне - несложный.

Comment: DialogBlocks хотя бы работает. Видимо, надо смотреть в эту сторону

Answer (score 2):

В Code::Blocks есть редактор для диалогов и фреймов. Он сделан в виде плагина wxSmith. Также, можно использовать внешний wxFormBuilder. CB умеет работать с обоими вариантами. Но библиотеку wxWidgets надо будет устанавливать самому и настраивать для себя окружение. Если бы Вы работали с MFC, то освоить работу с wxSmith и wxWidgets было бы довольно легко (и приятно, после того самого). Как это по сравнению с Builder не могу сказать, не люблю продукцию от Borland.

Comment: Ну, попробовал. С такой заумной установкой WxWindgets не вариант, похоже. Максимально допустимое количество действий выглядит так: установил библиотеку сетапом и указал где-то в настройках CodeBlocks, куда она установлена. А лучше вообще, чтобы настройку CodeBlocks сделал сам сетап. И дальше работаешь с формами и code behind.

Comment: Я не знаю, что именно в установке и настройке wx Вы не смогли сделать. На оф. сайте раздают уже готовые DLL (если они по какой-то причине не устраивают - их можно пересобрать самому. на вики у wx описано как). Нужно скачать эти библиотеки, распаковать, установить системную переменную окружения WX (например) с путем к каталогу с wx (внутри которого лежат подкаталоги include и lib). А потом, при создании проекта в CodeBlocks нужно указать, что библиотеки можно найти через эту переменную и что Вы используете shared (dll) немонолитную версию (именно такую дают на оф. сайте). И все.

Comment: Ну вот у меня к CodeBlocks подключен MinGW, потому что он в комплекте поставки. Если ставить компилятор отдельно, а потом настраивать пути к нему в CodeBlocks, то он не работает (отладчик точно не работает, возможно, компилятор тоже). Но на сайте готовые DLL только TDM либо Visual C++. И какую тогда брать? Про системную переменную тоже непонятно, Вы имеете в виду в Windows переменную окружения или в настройках CodeBlocks? И ещё, как правильно в такой ситуации пользоваться данным форумом, тут же нет лички, и долгие дискуссии в комментариях запрещены? У меня же наверняка будет куча вопросов.

Comment: 1. Лучше не используйте компилятор, который идет с CB - он очень сильно урезан. По моему опыту - с wx он работает очень плохо. 
Я обычно ставлю mingw-w64 (posix threads и SJLJ для 32 бит, SEH - для 64 бит). 
Но можно взять и TDM. Другой компилятор (и gdb) не работают, 
т.к. в CB почему-то до сих пор по умолчанию используют старые версии имен. 
Я их обычно в CB меняю сразу на gcc и g++ (они всегда есть у mingw). 
А к отладчику - просто надо указать полный путь в настройках (отдельный пункт меню).

Comment: 2. Mingw TDM и mingw-w64 вроде совместимы. Но надо только в рамкам одного ABI mingw. 
GCC 4.9.x нормально дружит с библиотеками для GCC 4.8.x, 
а вот для GCC 6 и 7- придется пересобирать wx 
(вообще, это не сложно, просто немножко долго. У меня минут 20 на одну версию библиотеки). 

3. Да, можно использовать Windows переменную (обращение из CB к ней: $(WX) - почти как в Unix), 
а можно и внутреннюю у CB (но тут надо читать документацию.. обращение к ней, вроде через такую конструкцию: $(#WX)).

Comment: 4. Про общение... Через какое-то количество комментариев просто предложат перейти в персональный чат для обсуждения (и дадут ссылку на него).

Comment: Да я собирал уже двумя компиляторами WxWidgets. Просто это всё равно не работает. Ругается на отсутствие конфигураций для Debug и Release.

Comment: Так, эта ошибка перестала вылезать (но на самом деле это ещё хуже, т.к. неизвестно, что будет в классе), зато теперь куча ошибок в файле chkconf.h, ругается на более чем 50 неопределённых макросов.

Comment: @Modus, Можно попробовать TeamViewer.. Или мне сюда придется слать много ответов со скриншотами.. Как Вам удобнее? chkconf.h - это может означать неверные настройки проекта.

Comment: Какой у Вас сейчас gcc? Может, у меня есть собранная версия под него. И как я говорил, у меня все 32-битные mingw на основе SJLJ + POSIX...

Comment: Есть ещё Skype, как вариант, у меня нет TeamViewer (но думаю, что ставить его проще, чем WxWindets :)))). По большому счёту, мы пока вообще склоняемся к тому, чтобы дизайнер показать в Visual Studio.NET - пофиг, что managed, хотя бы работает. Правда, я намедни сталкивался с тем, что на комп одного из клиентов Visual Studio тоже не встала, и пришлось использовать Sharp Develop. Но там-то это не проблема, т.к. нужен был C# + ASP.NET MVC, а не C++...

Comment: У меня плохо работает добавление контактов в Skype, но у меня Вы нашлись. Мне через Web-клиент попробовать Вас добавить, или мой запрос и так виден?

Comment: @Modus, да, увидел.